# Work with .JSON file in ReactJS for real beginners

Tags: reactjs

I've searched but not found anything so I'm confused on it. I don't know how do I search what I want to do as I'm real beginner and learning programming. So lets understand my questions...

- Firstly, **how to integrate or configure .JSON file with REACTJS**?
- Secondly, is there any way **to save data in .JSON file or somewhere else**. For example, I have a form to post articles in my website, if I fill such form and form data should save in `.JSON file permanently`.
- At last, `call/fetch this data to display` as article on the home page

Your help and guide would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you'd like to write to and read from a json file from reactjs?

If so you will find this hard to do as your client side he won't have much access to your file system.

You can use your browser's local storage; you can save your json data into local storage as a key value pair.

To use localStorage; you can do so as follows:

```
function loadJson() {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('json_file'));
}

function saveJson(data) {
    localStorage.setItem('json_file', JSON.stringify(data));
}
```

So, the loadJson will return you a JS object that is from the JSON stored in the localStorage, with key 'json_file'. The saveJson will take a JS object (data) and turn it into JSON and save it as the value of the key 'json_file' in localStorage.

Comment: How to use browser's local storage?

Comment: I have edited my answer to show how to use localStorage - there are many resources online to show how this can be done - it is simply a key/value store that your browser uses.